# How to disable folder timestamp update in NTFS

Tags: windows

Every time a file is updated (saved, deleted, moved to/from) in NTFS, the folder it resides on is touched to current time.

In exFat (or any other FAT) this does not happen.

How can this be disabled in NTFS?

Answer (score 1):

#### How can this be disabled in NTFS?

Instructions below.

Set the value to `1` (NTFS does not update the last-access timestamp, and it does not record time stamp updates in the NTFS log.)

Note: This will disable last-access timestamps for both file *and* directory access.

> **Suppress NTFS Volume Last Access Timestamp**
>
> By default, the LastAccess timestamp is updated whenever a directory
>   is accessed on a NTFS volume. This tweak eliminates the updating of
>   the timestamps.
>
> - [Start] [Run] [Regedit]
> - Registry Key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`
> - Modify/Create the Value Data Type(s) and Value Name(s) as detailed below.
> - Data Type: REG_DWORD [Dword Value] // Value Name: `NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate`
> - Setting for Value Data: [`0` = Suppression Disabled / `1` = Suppression Enabled]
> - Exit Registry and Reboot

Source [Suppress NTFS Volume Last Access Timestamp](http://www.theeldergeek.com/suppress_ntfs_volume_last_access_timestamp.htm)

Comment: Thank you David, but what I need is for folders only. And the other thing is, strangely enough this NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate does not work. I have it set, and fsutil behavior query DisableLastAccess is 1. Say I created D:\Folder\One with its contents last week and today I delete D:\Folder\One\Two, now in explorer D:\Folder\One shows its accessed today. I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: @ComputerUser If you delete something (as distinct from just reading the folder) it has to be updated ... as the folder contents have changed. That is how NTFS works.

Comment: So I guess it's impossible to set ntfs to behave a bit like exFAT. Thanks David.